# What is the length of Java log4j's log message's max length? How to print it in a single line?

Tags: java, log4j

In log4j default logging configuration, each line of log message which is printed in server log has maximum length comes around 8221 characters. If it exceeds this length, it is printed in multiple lines. But I want to print it in a single line, though whatever the length of each log message has.

Comment: I really wonder who is going to read 8221+ char length log messages...

Comment: @Pascal A program that parses server logs by line doesn't care how long a line is, nor should it.

Comment: Length of a line is not a matter. The program will parse. But each log message in a server.log(JBOSS) should be in a single line.

Comment: For the sake of anyone reading these logs, let them break across multiple lines. In fact, if 8221 is not enough for your purposes, cut out some of the logged information.

Answer (score 1):

To get log print in a single line, What I did is, I configured PatternLayout like value="%m%n", without configuring date format and etc..

```
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/>
</layout>
```

This is what my need & get solved.

Answer (score 0):

It will limit the line size to 1000 charactors.